# How play music with Ubuntu 18.04 using Airplay?

Tags: wireless, music, streaming, audio-player, airplay

Like on Macintosh (or even Windows, I suppose), iTunes will immediately recognize and use wireless streaming to play music via an Airplay device. I want my Ubuntu to do that. Simultaneous output, separate volume controls, play/pause, etc.

(BTW iTunes works fine, even the compact version from my iPad.)

I installed paprefs which gave Gnome a GUI, when installed with pulseaudio-module-raop, it adds a sound device, as advertised. But when I load my audio-player (tried many...) and play music, no sound is emitted when I select that device, although it will play fine on using the desktop-speakers - when selected. It never asked for the password. (I suspect this is why it doesn't work).

(I have tried many suggestions on ~oogle and all have failed.) Also I've tried many solutions (like airplay.jar, open-airplay, etc.) and they don't work with 18.04 and most are no longer maintained.

Hopefully there just an audio-player (like iTunes) for Ubuntu 18.04 that just plays to desktop-speakers as well as my home theatre.

Otherwise I can attempt to build from the code in say, open-airplay...

Ideas / suggestions... Has any Ubuntu users got a similar situation working - if so, how?

Comment: Does the information in https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2/issues/71 not help?

Comment: @dobey no.  It just leads me further down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Does your airplay device require a password to stream audio to it?

Comment: @dobey Yes it requires a password but the link doesn't give the exact command to use!

Comment: Yes it does. Read the comments on the issue! You need to unload the module, and then load it with all necessary options.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the issue at https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2/issues/71 you will need to pass all necessary options at load time of the module. You can see a list of supported parameters at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/blob/master/src/modules/raop/module-raop-sink.c#L35

This gets you something like:

```
pacmd load-module module-raop-sink --name=X --sink_name=Y --server=Z ... --username=foo --password=bar
```